# An IF statement is resulting in a Catch error message

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP form where one of the fields in the SQL table shows up as a link. However I want it to display something other than the field data and only if that field has something in it. 
It's a gig list and I want the option of displaying a link to the 'setlist'. I don't want it to display the filename though as it does now, but an image icon or something like 'SET'.

Someone suggested I add

```
if ($row['gigsetlist']=="") {
```

to the code but this has thrown up a Unexpected Catch.. error message.

Below is the code with the above if statement included. 
Can someone point out what else might be missing or conflicting?

```
<?php 

try {

    require_once "pdo_testdb_connect.php";

    $dbh = testdb_connect ();

    $sql = "SELECT id, gigdate,  date_format(gigdate,'%d %M') as d, gigshortdesc, 
    gigsetlist FROM gigs WHERE gigdate 
    BETWEEN '1995-01-01' AND '1995-12-31' ORDER BY gigdate ASC";

    print '<table>';

    foreach($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        print '<tr>
        <td width=100>' . $row['d']  . ' </td>
        <td> ' . $row['gigshortdesc'] . '</td>
        <td>';
        if ($row['gigsetlist']=="")
        {
            print '<a href="sets/' . $row['gigsetlist'] . '.php" 
            onclick="return openWin  (this.href, 

            this.target, 480, 480, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);" 
            rel="nofollow" target="_setlist">' . $row['gigsetlist'] . '</a></td>
            </tr>';
        }

    }

    print '</table>';

    $dbh = null;

}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage()
;}?>
```

Many thanks

Comment: I don't know if it happend by mistake, but you forgot one ending `}`. I formated your code and inserted the missing `}`. Beside that, the if statement does not make sense to me. Don't you mean `if($row['gigsetlist']!="")`?

Comment: Thanks Sascha. Yes it was the !== I had overlooked. And a } went astray too as you pointed out. Many thanks. It works perfectly well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

From:

```
if ($row['gigsetlist']=="")
```

To:

```
if ($row['gigsetlist']!="")
```

You have to check $row['gigsetlist'] not equal to empty which means it contains some data then display the link.

Comment: Thank you @Satish that has worked brilliantly. Of course, should have spotted that. Many thanks